# Auto-Scaling removes running task in ECS service (FARGATE)

Tags: amazon-ecs, autoscaling, aws-fargate

I am running an ecs service using Fargate on AWS. Each task there completes a single operation and dies (fetching a message from a SQS queue and decode/encode a video file). Now I designed an autoscaling policy like below,

1. If SQS queue size is more than 5 increment desired count to 1 (repeat every 60 seconds).
2. If SQS queue size is less than 2 decrement desired count to 1 (repeat every 60 seconds).

But what AWS is doing is than when queue size gets down below 2, it kills out running tasks leaving the corresponding operation "broken". I don't want AWS to kill the running tasks (because they will automatically die within sometime when the command completes) but just to set the desired count to 0 so that the tasks doesn't get "respawned". So literally I want my tasks to be unstoppable during auto-scaling.

How I can achieve this in ECS service and aws_ecs_autoscaling_target. Please note that I am using terraform to provision the service.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked into autoscaling cool-down period? Set that for 60s then, no matter what, no more than 1 task will be removed at a minimum interval of 60s. With a desired count of 0 it might do the trick.

Comment: David J Eddy Here the trouble is that sometime the runtime is uncertain. It might take a lot more. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to solve this issue in a different approach. I had to create a small Lambda function which gets triggered by the cloudwatch alarm and starts a Fargate task using StartTask. This workflow suited well here rather than using autoscaling policy.

Comment: I am facing same issue, Can you help me on it. My tasks are also getting destroyed even they are in running state

Comment: I have similar problem, can you share your solutions?

Answer (score 0):

[Task Scale-in protection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-scale-in-protection.html) has been launched, a new capability that gives you control over protecting Amazon ECS service tasks from being terminated by scale-in events from Amazon ECS service Auto Scaling or deployments.

More info at https://aws.amazon.com/es/blogs/containers/announcing-amazon-ecs-task-scale-in-protection/

Code example:

```
async function pollForWork() {
  console.log('Acquiring task protection');
  await TaskProtection.acquire();

  var message = await receiveMessage();

  if (message) {
    await processMessage(message);
  }

  console.log('Releasing task protection');

  await TaskProtection.release();
  return maybeContinuePolling();
}
```